# How to `yarn add` without update other packages?

Tags: npm, yarnpkg, package-managers

I have wrote some packages which has no dependencies at all and I put those packages on my private Gitlab. And I want to install them with `yarn add GIT_URL_TO_PACKAGE --module-folder=my_module`. The problem is that every time I add a new package, `yarn` will install all other packages in `package.json`. But I want only install the package specified in the command.

Is there an option to `yarn add` or some tricks to this?

FYI:

I just want a `"package manager"` to download code from my private Gitlab and record the package tag/version/sha1. `Yarn` is just a tool that pop into my head. If `npm` or other package manager can do these, I would be glad to switch to that.

Comment: Have you found any solution? For me also, while adding any package, it is affecting other packages.

Comment: No, I haven't.   : - (

Comment: @Sujit, I wrote a simple tool to download directory from a repository and save it's information into a json file. It meets my needs. Hope it will help. https://github.com/aztack/download-repo-dir

Answer (score 6):

Old question but still relevant today.

I created [`yarn-add-no-save`](https://github.com/darionco/yarn-add-no-save) to achieve this functionality. It can be installed local to your project or globally:

```
$ yarn add yarn-add-no-save --dev
# or
$ yarn global add yarn-add-no-save
```

Once installed you can simply run:

```
$ yarn add-no-save <packages> # (yarn-add-no-save when installed globally)
```

My use case is to test modules that declare `peerDependencies` so the tool has some options to automatically install them, to see all the options run:

```
$yarn add-no-save --help
```

NOTE: I am aware that saving a package to install packages without saving them is ironic and basically defeats the purpose, but this is the best I could come up with and it fits my needs.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I needed to quickly switch between branches that have non-conflicting dependency sets. What's ironic is that Yarn 1 tries to best NPM yet lacks in some areas by negligence.

Answer (score -2):

yarn install --check-files
Verifies that already installed files in node_modules did not get removed.

yarn install --flat
Install all the dependencies, but only allow one version for each package. On the first run this will prompt you to choose a single version for each package that is depended on at multiple version ranges. These will be added to your package.json under a resolutions field.